# Nested TestFixture in different classes

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit

I am trying to create a web automation that logs in and out just once. As the website is formed by different products I am required to build different sets of tests in different classes/files(Exaple: ReportsTests, AuthenticationTests, etc.) I am perfectly able to create a `TestFixture` which logs in and out using the `OneTimeSetup` and `OneTimeTearDown` but that happens once for every class.

What I am trying to create is a `TestFixture` within a `TestFixure` in a way that the Login and Logout happens once on the first `TestFixture` and the second execute the sets of tests.

So far I've got this:

Setup.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace TestsSetup
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestSetup
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login in");
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login out");
        }
    }
}
```

TestSuit.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;
using System;
using TestsSetup;

namespace TCISuiteSetup
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class CWTestSuite : TestSetup
    {
        [TestFixture(1)]
        public class SuiteSetup
        {
            [OneTimeSetUp]
            public void Setup()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing happens on this step");
            }

            [OneTimeTearDown]
            public void Teardown()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing happens on this step");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test1.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;
using System;
using TCISuiteSetup;

namespace TCI.Tests
{
    [TestFixture(1)]
    public class UserManagerTests : CWTestSuite.SuiteSetup
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

test2.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;
using System;
using TCISuiteSetup;

namespace TCI.Tests
{
    [TestFixture(1)]
    public class ReportTests : CWTestSuite.SuiteSetup
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the test like this all tests fail. If I remove the `(1)` from the `TestFixture(1)` it pass everything but it does not hit any of the `[OneTimeSetup]/[OneTimeTearDown]` if I change the `UserManagerTests : TestSuite.SuiteSetup` to `UserManager : TestSetup` it hits just the first `[TestFixture]`

Am I missing anything.

Comment: Is there a reason to not derive SuitSetup from TestSetup like this :`public class SuitSetup :TestSetup` ?

Comment: There is no reason. This is the first step to remake an automation that is completely inefficient so any idea is welcome. However, if I do that all the test keep failing.

Answer (score 1):

dNesting of test fixture classes has no meaning whatsoever to NUnit. For a few years we have talked about making it meaningful, but never did anything about it.

SO, in terms of test fixtures, `CWTestSuite` and `CWTestSuite.SetUpFixture` have no relationship at all. It's just as if they were defined separately, without nesting.

If you want one fixture to group fixtures, NUnit provides `SetUpFixture`, which is a way to define one-time setup and teardown behavior that applies across multiple classes. A `SetUpFixture` is defined for a particular namespace and essentially wraps all the `TestFixtures` defined within that namespace and subordinate namespaces.

For example, if you were to put all your `TestFixtures` in some common namespace, then you could add a `SetUpFixture` in the same namespace like this...

```
namespace Some.Common.Namespace
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class TestSetup
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login in");
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login out");
        }
    }

    public class UserManagerTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }

    public class ReportTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have made no use of inheritance in this example. It's not required and would break things if I had used it. If you need some common initialization logic for **some but not all** of the fixtures in the namespace, then you can give them a common base class, but that **must be separate** from the `SetUpFixture` and should ideally be abstract.

As a minor note, I removed all redundant `[TestFixture]` annotations. That's the style I recommend.

Comment: I tried that and it keeps running once per class. It does run like:

`OneTimeSetUp/SetUpFixture
OneTimeSetUp/TestFixture
OneTimeTearDown/TestFixture
OneTimeTearDown/SetUpFixture`

Comment: We are talking about one-time __per test run__ aren't we? That is, every time you select run. If you wanted to have a single login for an interactive VS session, that would be out of scope for NUnit.

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't work. I'll enlarge the example to make sure we are talking about the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way but maybe it is not the most elegant:

Setup.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace TestsSetup
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class CWTestSuite : TestSetup
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class SuiteSetup
        {
            static private bool isLoggedOn;

            [OneTimeSetUp]
            public void TestSuiteSetup()
            {
                if (isLoggedOn == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Loggin happens here");
                    isLoggedOn = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [SetUpFixture]
    public class TestSetup
    {
        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login out happens here");
        }

        [TestFixture]
        public class Testing
        {
            [Test]
            public void Test1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("All tests for this product has been executed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any of the test.cs matching the following format

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;
using System;
using static TestsSetup.CWTestSuite;

namespace TestSetup
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UserManagerTests : SuiteSetup
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test4()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assertion");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

1. I could not get rid of the `[TestFixture]` within the `[TestFixture]` (Setup.cs/public class CWTestSuite). If I delete it it will hit the `[OneTimeTearDown]` after running the tests in a class.
2. I had to add a flag on the login steps as that `[OneTimeSetUp]` is called at the beginning of every set of tests.
3. The only way I found to trigger the `[OneTimeTearDown]` was to add a `[TestFixture]/[Test]` afterwards. it is called at the very end and it may just print a console.log but it needs to be there and it needs to be called.

BTW. This is a possible solution/work around but not recommended at all. If you want to do something like this I recommend using NUnit + SpecFlow (The `[BeforeTestRun]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: A `TestFixture` should never inherit from a `SetUpFixture`. Making the `SetUpFixture` a base class guarantees that the `OneTimeSetUp` will run `n + 1` times, where `n` is the number of `TestFixtures`.

Comment: BTW, it's an embarassment that we don't detect that and give an error. Frankly, I never imagined anybody doing that, but no worries because you're far from the first!

Comment: Definitely that wasn't a good idea. It was the only possible way I found at the time but I stopped going that way. Right now I am working on NUnit + SpecFlow and I have to say that it is way easier. Still having some troubles to connect different projects within a solution but I could not get to this point using that method before. Thanks anyways for your help =)